# Express static work only with filename index.html

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So i have a problem with my static files. Here's my code:

```
const express = require ('express')

const app = express()

app.listen(4040,() => console.log("on"))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"))
```

Everything works. Until I change html file name in public folder
It works if it's index.html but doesn't if it's about.html or everything else.

My folders are like that:

```
Main
    node_modules
    public
        assets
            style.css
        index.html/about.html
    main.js
    package-lock.json
    package.json
```

Comment: Why are you showing `index.html/about.html` in your file listing? What is that?

Comment: Which url are you visiting? `http://localhost:4040/about.html`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route must be specific, "/" for "index.html" & "/about" for "about.html". If you change from index.html to home.html, make sure your main.js (server) also follows.

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public/index.html"));
});

app.get("/about", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public/about.html"));
});

app.listen(4040, () => console.log("on"));
```

index.html (http://localhost:4040/)

```
<h1>HOME PAGE</h1>
```

about.html (http://localhost:4040/about)

```
<h1>ABOUT PAGE</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I believe I might know what's going on but wanted to clarify, you are wanting to serve multiple static files one "index.html" and another "about.html" and it's only working for the one called index.html? If this is the case this is because it defaults to reading the index.html file if it is present, the solution to this may be to rename your index.html to something else such as main.html, and see if that works properly.

Comment: Only the `/` route defaults to `index.html`.  A request for `/about` or `/about.html` would read `about.html` just fine if it was present.

Comment: I know that but that may actually be what he is accidentally doing, I recall when I first started working with express I started developing a contact page before the home page and I set the / route to serve the static file for the contact.html since that was what I was working with first and wanted to make it easier to get to when working so I could just type the address without anything extra, and it kept serving the empty HTML page from index.html, figured this could be the same mistake but it's also kind of vague question.